# Typescript doesnt wait before executing next sql

Tags: mysql, typescript, async-await

I am using NestJS and Mysql without using TypeORM.
I need to execute 2 or more simple SQL's, second SQL will use result from the first SQL. The problem is although I am using async/await the program doesnt wait for getUser() to complete before processing getGetMenuParents() . Hence the role passed as argument to getGetMenuParents() is undefined.
Please help me to identify the problem.

```
async findMenu(header) {  
    if (!header.userid) throw new HttpException('Userid not supplied', HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    let a = await this.getUser(header.userid)           
    let b = await this.getGetMenuParents(a[0].role)
    return b[0];
}

async getUser(userid:string) {
    const sql =`select role from gb_users where userid = '${userid}'`
    const result  = await this.conn.query(sql);
    return result;
}

async getGetMenuParents(role:string) {
    const sql =`select * from gb_roles where role = '${role}'`;   
    const result  = await this.conn.query(sql);
    return result;
}
```

Regards,
Suraj

This is my connection

```
const dbProvider = {
    inject: [ConfigService],
    provide: DB_CONNECTION,
    useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
    return await mysql.createConnection({
        user: configService.get<string>('database.username'),
        host:  configService.get<string>('database.host'),
        database:  configService.get<string>('database.database'),
        password:   configService.get<string>('database.password'),
        port: parseInt( configService.get<string>('database.port'), 3306),
     })
   },
};
```

I tried changing DB_CONNECTION to "ASYNC_CONNECTION"

Comment: Can you format your code? Is really difficult to read it right now.

Comment: Hi Suraj, can you please also add the database schema (or a simplified version), since there do not seem to be any blatant issues in the code provided, apart from the SQL injection from string interpolation, as well as `.query` not having type safety.

Comment: Hi @EliasSchablowski , Thanks for your comments and concerns which I agree but that doenst stop the async/await. Below are the simple 2 tables used by above code.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `gb_users` (
  `USERID` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `USERNAME` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ROLE` char(12) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`USERID`),
  KEY `GB_USERS_FK3` (`ROLE`),
  CONSTRAINT `gb_users_fk3` FOREIGN KEY (`ROLE`) REFERENCES `gb_roles` (`ROLE`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `gb_roles` (
  `ROLE` char(12) NOT NULL,
  `ROLEDESC` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ROLE`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Answer (score 1):

According to your DB specification, the field is in all-caps, therefore the sql should also use all-caps:

```
async findMenu(header) {  
    if (!header.userid) throw new HttpException('Userid not supplied', HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    let a = await this.getUser(header.userid)           
    let b = await this.getGetMenuParents(a[0].role)
    return b[0]; // Data is 
}

async getUser(userid:string) {
    const sql =`select ROLE as role from gb_users where USERID = '${userid}'`
    const result  = await this.conn.query(sql);
    return result;
}

async getGetMenuParents(role:string) {
    const sql =`select * from gb_roles where ROLE = '${role}'`;   
    const result  = await this.conn.query(sql);
    return result;
}
```

Though something like this would probably be preferable since it uses the query builder abstraction to mitigate SQL injection:

```
async findMenu(header) {  
    if (!header.userid) throw new HttpException('Userid not supplied', HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    let a = await this.getUser(header.userid)           
    let b = await this.getGetMenuParents(a.role)
    return b[0];
}

async getUser(userid:string) {
    const result = this.conn
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .select("ROLE", "role")
        .from("gb_users")
        .where("gb_users.USERID = :id", { id: userid })
        .getOne();
    return result;
}

async getGetMenuParents(role:string) {
    const result = this.conn
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .select("ROLE", "role") // make sure these are lower case as well, since this is most likely assumed further down the code.
        .select("ROLEDESC", "roledesc")
        .from("gb_roles")
        .where("gb_roles.ROLE = :role", { role })
        .getMany();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This sort of chained query is usually a bad idea, and can be replaced by a single query with a JOIN.

In your case you can replace the two separate queries

```
select role from gb_users where userid = '${userid}'
select * from gb_roles where role = '${role}'
```

With a single query:

```
select * from gb_users left join gb_roles using(role) where userid='${userid}'
```

which matches  `gb_roles` to `gb_users` on the `role` column, then returns everything from both tables, filtered by `userid`

Your code above becomes:

```
async findMenu(header) {  
   
    if (!header.userid) throw new HttpException('Userid not supplied', HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);

    const sql =`select * from gb_users left join gb_roles using(role) where userid='${userid}'`
    const result  = await this.conn.query(sql);
    return result[0];
}
```

SQL Demo:https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jpZC7WzUVWRPB1wFFJhwVW/0

**Note** This addresses the gist of your question by eliminating the second query. The code is vulnerable to SQL injections (as is yours). I refer you to the answer by Elias for methods to combat that threat.